# Writing a binary search method, struggling to return 1 (true) when a word is found in an array. [Homework}

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a simple spell checking program for homework, basically by putting a dictionary of 80,000 words into an array and then doing a binary search to see if the word is in the array.

I believe the problem is to do with the first if statement, with my break and return 1 lines, but I may be wrong. What I'm trying to do is make it so that if the word at the midpoint of the array is the same as the string, then it should break out of the if statement and the while loop and return 1, if it's not the same I want it to continue searching.

Currently every time I run the program it says the word is not found, whether the word is actually in the dictionary or not.

Any help with where I am going wrong is greatly appreciated.

```
int binarySearch(char string[9]) {
  int low = 0;
  int high = NUMBEROFDICTIONARYWORDS;
  int midPoint;
  char midPointWord[9];

  while(high > (low + 1)) {

    midPoint = (low + high) / 2;
    midPointWord[9] = dictionary[midPoint];

    if(strcmp(string, midPointWord) == 0) {
    return 1;
    break;
    break;
    } else
    if(strcmp(string, midPointWord) < 0) {
    high = midPoint;
    } else
  low = midPoint;
  }

  return 0;

}
```

Comment: Can you give your definition for `dictionary`?  The problem implies it should be `char *dictionary[]`, but your usage implies it is `char dictionary[]`.

Comment: I have defined it like this: string dictionary[NUMBEROFDICTIONARYWORDS];

Comment: There's no point in putting `break`s after `return 1;`.  `return` automatically breaks out of anything between it and the point at which the function was called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`midPointWord[9] = dictionary[midPoint];` only assigns index 9 of midPointWord, which in this case is an invalid thing to do because it is past the end of the array. I'm guessing `dictionary` is something like a `char**`, in which case you want to declare midPointWord as `char*`.

Comment: @Matt: Further note that `midPointWord[9] = dictionary[midPoint];` does _not_ copy the entire word -- there's no "easy" mechanism in C for copying an array via assignment. (You don't want the copy _anyway_; this is just a warning in case you haven't experienced this yet.)

Comment: Thanks, a very silly mistake on my part! By the way, if I was to change it to midPointWord = dictionary[midPoint]; would it work?

Comment: @MattHarris, that would not fix it without also changing the type of midPointWord. There is no "built-in" syntax for copying array contents in C. There is a standard library function called `memcpy` which copies array contents, but you can avoid copying in this case by using pointers.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I haven't quite got my head around pointers yet but I will look into it.